# How do I use a dataframe in SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two dataframes of demographic and medication data that I created from a pipe-delimited file:

```
demo='xxyy1046_demo.txt'
demog=pd.read_table(demo, delimiter='|', header=0)
demog.info()

med='xxyy1046_medication.txt'
meds=pd.read_table(med, delimiter='|', header=0)
meds.info() #n=2654
```

I now want to use SQLalchemy to convert these dataframes in SQL table objects that I can select, join, group_by, etc.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, column, select, Table, Metadata
engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)
demog.to_sql('Demog_sql', con=engine)

metadata = sql.Metadata()
demog_sql = Table('Demog_sql', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
stmt = select([demog_sql.columns.FirstName]) 
print(stmt)
```

I get the result:
SELECT "Demog_sql"."FirstName" 
FROM "Demog_sql"

This is not what I want! I want to be able to manipulate the data using select statements, joins, etc. I am doing something wrong with the metadata step. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the string representation of the statement object itself. It seems you would like to execute it instead. For example:

```
results = engine.execute(stmt).fetchall()
```

For joins and the like you would call further methods on your statement, best explained in the [tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html), which you should read before you continue.

In some cases you do not need to upload your data to SQL for joins etc. [Pandas can do those too](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) between dataframes.